# How can Azure MobileServiceClient be used to upload files?

Tags: c#, azure, mobile, xamarin

I am developing a mobile client on Xamarin with a server on Azure Mobile Service.
I use Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient to send application/json messages to the server.
Now I need to upload files too.
How can I use form/multipart with MobileServiceClient?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Mobile Services only use data in tables, no files at all. Therefore, the `MobileServicesClient` is only built to exchange with table data.

You might use other Azure services like Blob Storage to put files there.

---

If you only need to store really small images, you can put them into the database as textdata, but this has many limitations. Chris Risner has a [tutorial on his Blog.](http://chrisrisner.com/Storing-Images-from-Android-in-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services)